# ng-show/ng-hide limit multiple calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to limit the call of ng-hide/ng-show. Currently, what it does is it calls the getLicense function multiple times that will overloads the browser.

```
$scope.getLicense = function( value ) {

    if( $sessionStorage.license === '' ) {
        DashboardService.getLicense( ).then( function( data ) {
            $scope.licenses = data;
            var arr = [ ],
                id = '';
            for( var i in $scope.licenses ) {
                arr.push( [ i ] );
            }
            $sessionStorage.license = arr;
        } );

        for( var cnt = 0; cnt < $sessionStorage.license.length; cnt++ ) {
            if( $sessionStorage.license[ cnt ] == value ) {
                console.log( 'true' );
                return true;
                break;
            } else {
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
            for( var cnt = 0; cnt < $sessionStorage.license.length; cnt++ ) {
            if( $sessionStorage.license[ cnt ] == value ) {
                console.log('true');
            return true;
                break;
            } else {
                console.log('false');
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

};
```

My HTML code looks like this:

```
   <md-list-item class="md-caption" ng-class="{'active': $state.includes('security.webcontrol')}" translate="SIDEBAR.NAV.WEBCONTROL.TITLE"  ng-hide="getLicense('web_control_da')">
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving a function to `ng-show` / `hide` / `if` / etc is **a very bad practice**.

Each time `$digest` is called (*very often*) it check each watcher to see if it has changed. So it will have to execute your function to know if the result is different (or not).

Add a `console.log('function executed')` in your function `getLicense` and you will see how often it is called.

To avoid that (like *Icycool* explained) you have to replace that by a boolean in your scope. And only change the boolean when `getLicense` should be tested.

**For example :** If `getLicense` need to be calculated each time `$sessionStorage.license` change (for example) :

```
$scope.licence = getLicense();

$scope.watch("$sessionStorage.license", function (newValue, oldValue){
    $scope.licence = getLicense();
});
```

And in your view/template : `ng-hide="licence"`

*So it will execute your `getLicense` only when it does really matter.*

Comment: Here's it goes.. I'm expecting a value from the function that I'm getting from the HTML side. which is in this case "web_control_da"

Comment: I got your first point about the calls. I have noticed that actually which I know will crash the browser :( @antoine

Comment: And where does this "web_control_da" comes from ? Add it to the scope or use `ng-init="licenseValue='web_control_da'"` or stmg.

Comment: "web_control_da" comes from the html. It is actually a hardcoded value which I will be checking on the getLicense function.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to a scope variable and have `ng-hide` point to that instead. Call check license on other occasions.